# Improving performance mongdb

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, performance

is there any way i can improve the performance of my mongodb query?

I have a database with around 60.000 documents, it's going to grow alot bigger so i need to start looking at performance.

i have a list of ID's im looping through to find the right documents and then filtering by number of employees. The ID list is generated by another query just before in another collection.

```
id_list = ['12412412', '42141241', '41241241', etc...]

for i in id_list:
    keyword = '{}.employees'.format(i)
    query = db.collection.find_one({keyword: {'$gt': 2}}, {'_id': False})
    result.append(query)
```

running a query like this takes around 27 seconds.

the structure of the collection looks like this.

```
{
'412412421': {
    'name':'company name',
    'employees': 3,
    etc...
    }, 
'512457300': {
    'name':'company name',
    'employees': 27,
    etc...
    } ...
}
```

The query is now running on developement server with a mechanical harddrive 7200 rpm. I think it will be faster on ssd disk but surely its possible to increase the performance of this?

Is there a better way to run the query instead of in a loop like that?

---

I managed to optimise the query, Solution for this if anyone else might find it useful. I changed the structure of the collection like this:

```
{
    {
    'name':'company name',
    'id': '412412421',
    'employees': 3,
    etc...
    }, 
    {
    'name':'company name',
    'id': '512457300',
    'employees': 27,
    etc...
    } ...
}
```

Then i added indexing for id with:

```
db.collection.create_index([('id', pymongo.DESCENDING)])
```

And last i changed the query to find instead of find_one

```
query = db.collection.find({'id':{'$in':id_list }, 'employees': {'$gt': 2}}, {'_id': False})

for q in query:
    result.append(q)
```

running this now takes 0.3 seconds.